# How to prevent exec error in using system() in perl

Tags: perl, exec, tk-toolkit

I'm creating a task manager using perl Tk with the following code.

```
my $mw=MainWindow->new;
$mw->title("Task Manager");
$numproc = `ps|wc -l`;
$i=2;
@a=1;
while($i <= $numproc){
    my $p=`sh printproc.sh $i`;
    system($p);
    $mw->Checkbutton(-text=>$p)->pack;
    $i=$i+@a;

}
MainLoop;
```

printproc.sh has the following

```
ps|head -$1|tail -1
```

I get a window with each process listed as a checkButton, but I get the following error for each process.

> Can't exec "2645":No such file or directory at first.pl line 11.

How do I avoid this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
my $p=`sh printproc.sh $i`;
system($p);
```

This takes the output of running `printproc.sh` and stores it in `$p`, and then tries to execute that as if it were a command.  Remove the `system($p);` line.